# LinkedIn permission approval not working?

Tags: permissions, linkedin-api, spring-social-linkedin

I have create an app in LinkedIn developer account. Also I need company page permission access to access details of company page. After creating app and requested the developer product which sent me email. I have completed the details and submitted the request. I am waiting since 1 month but it is not getting approved nor rejected. It is still in "Review in progress" stage. What is probable time to get it approved after submitting the request. Is there any way to fix this or any support email where I should contact for the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn usually takes 90 business days to process the request.

If you want to speed up the process , raise a ticket on [LinkedIn Developer Support Portal](https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us)

hope this helps you